# What is the modern replacement for right-click "lock to launcher"

Tags: 20.04, launcher

What is the most modern and convenient solution to the absence of the right-click "Lock to Launcher" feature.

I'm on 20.04 and the feature is not available on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the "Add to favorites" option in the right-click menu of an icon on the dock, which will cause an icon to stay on the launcher even if it is not running. This option is only available provided the application has a corresponding desktop launcher file installed in either `~/.local/share/applications` or in an `application` folder in one of the folders listed in the XDG_DATA_DIRS environmental variable.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. Thanks. It is in "Show applications", right-click an application, "Add to favorites". If you describe this as "an icon on the dock" I would not be able to find it. I believe somebody calls "Show applications" a cheeseboard, which is a more apt visual metaphor.